# Start program with standard arguments (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, command-line-arguments

Is it possible for me to start a program with flags from Windows Explorer?

I want to start the Eclipse IDE with another Java Executable.

When I open eclipse.exe from Explorer it will of course run `eclipse.exe`.
But I want to run `eclipse.exe -vm "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/javaw.exe"`

Comment: "Is it possible for me to start a program with flags from Windows Explorer?" - Use a shortcut to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks. not the most elegant solution but it does the job. Thanks!

Comment: It kinda is the most elegant solution.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to set the arguments in the properties menu. but that's up to Microsoft to implement.

Comment: @MegaXLR  - That is how, you pass an argument to an executable in Windows, for over 2 decades.  The only other way is to use the command prompt to do it.